# is it possible to delete an in-app purchase while it is in Approved state?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

is it possible to delete an in-app purchase while it is in Approved state?
I have a product in app purchase with approved, and now I want to delete it in app purchase
How to do ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to delete an in-app purchase while it is in Approved state.

1 - Log in to iTunes Connect & navigate to "Manage Your Apps section"; chose your app in there.

2- Navigate to "Manage In-App Purchases"

3- Now you need to mark the approved in-app purchased to "NOT clear for sale". Click the first "Edit" button that lets you change the summary/details of the in-app purchase. A new form/page will open. Search for "Clear For Sale" option and select "No" against it. Save your change.

4- A "delete" button will now appear at the top left corner of in-app details page. Just click that button and the in-app will be deleted.